# Edit button in top right corner of screen

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, save, edit

I'm currently working on a "details" page for a specific item that is editable. The question is, when you have finished editing the details of the item, would it be more user friendly to put the save button where the "edit" button was (top right of the screen) or have the save button in a more traditional location such as at the bottom of the screen below the details? I have included pictures below.

[image]

Comment: I'd put the save button at the bottom, more common place for a save button. But as always, make prototypes and test with a few people (even just colleagues if that's all you can access).

Comment: I would suggest you to keep the button on top right corner or Position fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the position of the button will depend on a few factors, which I list as follows:

1. People's eye movement on the computer screen is always horizontal (moving left or right depends on the nature of the language which is displayed on screen) then downwards. So assuming that `Save` action is the final action that users will need to carry out in the task, the button should be located on the bottom right.
2. However, people are also used to standards, e.g. if the screen you drew is a modal, and for some reason all modals on your application have their buttons on the same top right positions, then users may expect your `Save` button to appear at the same place. And also if it's a modal, you have to be careful if the modal screen will overflow beyond the monitor display - you won't want the `Save` button to be hidden from users.
3. Lastly, because it was mentioned that you are working on a `details` page, I'm not sure if it'll be a modal. Would it be necessary to put a `Save` button in there to confirm the information saved or there is autosave feature that updates the records as users dismiss the `details` page. Then you'll help users hasten the process of working on the application.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are not any specific rules to put edit on the top right side only. But I would suggest to keep it there only. CTAs like save, proceed, next prev are mostly kept on bottom side and edit on top right within the box of editable content make more sense to me.